# How to use dictionaries in Python to link students to grades

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a complete beginner trying to teach myself Python. Currently working through a book and have just finished the chapter on using dictionaries.  Trying the exercises and have gotten stuck. I was hoping someone could give me some advice on how to solve a particular problem.  I've been tasked with the following exercise:

***Create a program that pairs a student's name to his class grade.  The user should be able to enter as many students as needed and then get a printout of all the students' names and grades.  The output should look like this:***

Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): [INPUT]
Please give me their grade: [INPUT]
[And so on...]
Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): q
Okay, printing grades!
Student    Grade
Student1   A
Student2   D
Student3   B
Student4   A
[And so on...]

Carefully consider what should be unique (and therefore used as a key) and what would probably not be unique (and therefore should be stored as a value)

I'm completely stuck about how to accomplish this. What's confusing me is what to use as the dictionary key(s) because they need to be unique. The student names can't be keys because you can have people with the same name.  And I don't think grades are unique either.

Can anyone help me out? Maybe show me some example code on how to accomplish this? Apologies if this seems like a stupid question and is totally obvious to all Python developers. I am a beginner as I said.

Comment: This is a difficult problem to solve generally. You could create a unique user id for each student, but for the simple task at hand its difficult how a dictionary would be better than a list to store the information. One trick is to ask for a valid email address... then you pushed the question of uniqueness off to a different entity.

Comment: I think the task assumes for simplicity that each student has a unique name (by "what would probably not be unique" I guess they mean the grades).

Comment: @mkrieger1 -  I don't know, "Carefully consider" doesn't shout "assumes for simplicity" to me.

Answer (score 0):

Question wants you to use a dictionary as a record book of students

```
st={}
q=None
while (q!='q'):
    q=input("Name of student:")
    t=input("Grade:")
    st[q]=t
print("Now printing grades")
for student,grade in in st.items():
    print(student,grade)
```

What you must have picked up is student names are more likely to be unique than grades so name is key and grade is value

Comment: The question is about dealing with like-named students. I guess this answer is to ignore the problem?

Comment: Uniqueness is to be forced while accepting data from user.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to force uniqueness as data is entered. Now the user has to figure out how to disambiguate names, but it does get you there.

```
def get_student_grades():
    student_grades = {}
    while True:
        student = input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit): ")
        if student =="q":
            return student_grades
        if student in student_grades:
            print("Student already registered, a different name is needed")
        else:
            student_grades[student] = input("Please give me their grade: ")


table = get_student_grades()
for student, grade in table.items():
    print(student, grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

To account for repeats we could use a list of lists or LoL. This would mainly be acceptable if you wanted to input all the grades and do some calculation on them. Not sure if the situation makes sense practically but here's my answer anyways.

```py
students = []
query = ""
while query != "q":
    query = input("Student Name ('q' to quit): ")
    if query == "q":
        break
    grade = input("Grade: ")
    students.append([query, grade])

print("Okay, printing grades!")
for student, grade in students:
    print("{} {}".format(student, grade))
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for all the comments and input.  It's extremely helpful.  That's given me a few ideas to try and different approaches to try to resolve the problem.  I think as a few of you have mentioned, the question isn't worded very well and perhaps it's implying that names should be the unique keys and grades should be the values.  I was thinking about going down the route of using unique ID numbers for each student as it seemed the most logical.  That's how it would work in a student database system anyway.  I

Comment: I also like the idea of forcing unique entry by not allowing the user to enter the same name twice.  As it's a beginner Python book that I'm working through then perhaps that's what they intended.  It would certainly simplify things a lot.  Many thanks for all the help everyone!  Now I can get that done and move on to the next chapter.

Comment: Hi everyone.  Many thanks for your help.  After a bit of playing around, I've managed to get it working the way I want.  Here's the code I came up with:

Answer (score 0):

If the same name appears, you can tell the user that the name has already appeared and if they wish to change the previously assigned grade. In this scenario you can't handle students with same name, but since no other information is given, this is the best you can do. Had information like unique id be present then you can easily assign name and grade to the unique id and everything would be fine.

here is the code:

```
students = {}
while True:
    inp = input("Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):")
    if inp == 'q':
        break
    if inp in students.keys():
        cmd = input("this student's grade is already inputed. Do you wish to change that grade?")
        if cmd != 'y':
            continue
    grade = input("Please give me their grade:")
    students[inp] = grade

print("Okay, printing grades!")
print("Student          Grade")
for key in students.keys():
    print(f"{key}{' '*(17-len(key))}{students[key]}")
```

output:

```
Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):abcd
Please give me their grade:A
Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):abcd
this student's grade is already inputed. Do you wish to change that grade?n
Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):abcde
Please give me their grade:B
Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):abcd
this student's grade is already inputed. Do you wish to change that grade?y
Please give me their grade:F
Please give me the name of the student (q to quit):q
Okay, printing grades!
Student          Grade
abcd             F
abcde            B
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just reject duplicate names

The exercise wants you to treat the student names as being unique, otherwise, when there are students with the same name, there would be no way to know which one to update when the only information presented is their name. The book just messed up. It should have told you to assume that no two people have the same name.

I would handle duplicate names as tdelaney suggested and make the program reject them, leaving it up to the teacher to come up with a way of renaming those students in the system.

Your program would then end up creating a dictionary that looks like this.

```
names_to_grade = {
 'Alice': 'A',
 'Bob': 'B',
 'Eve': 'F'
}
```

---

### But if you actually want to allow them

If you wanted to try to allow duplicate names, there are a few ways to go about it. All of them make the program a lot more difficult to create.

**Handling this from the teacher's perspective**

A) When updating a duplicate name, you could print out the duplicates on new lines with numbers by them like so:

```
Enter the number that corresponds to the student you would like to update:

1) Name=Alice Grade=A
2) Name=Alice Grade=B
```

B) The other option I can think of is to have a second prompt that asks for the grade, and then use the first duplicate name that has that grade. (If there are more than 1 students who have the same name+grade, it doesn't matter which one is updated. The result is identical. If it did matter you would have to keep prompting for more information until you got down to a single student.)

**Storing the duplicate entries**

The exercise wants us to use a dictionary, but we know we can't use the name or the grade as neither are unique. Using both pieces of information as a lookup key doesn't make much sense either. When you run out of options, you can always resort to using an ID. Like a Student ID! That's exactly why you received a student ID in school. If we assign everyone a unique ID starting at 1, we could create the following data structure:

```
students_dict = {
 1: {'name':'Alice', 'grade':'A'},
 2: {'name':'Bob', 'grade':'B'},
 3: {'name':'Eve', 'grade':'F'},
}
```

Notice how I've put dictionaries inside of a dictionary. This is perfectly valid. Now to find all of the students with a particular name we can do:

```
def find_by_name(looking_for):
    ''' Returns a list containing all of the students that have the name passed in '''
    ret = []

    # Loop over each student in the dictionary
    for student in students_dict.values():

        # Find the ones with our desired name
        if student['name'] == looking_for:

            # And add them to the ret list.
            ret.append(student)
    return ret
```

You would also need to create a function that can find a student based on a particular name + grade, and all of the code for the additional prompt that appears when a duplicate is detected.